# Disabling Add Spatial Database Connection function in ArcMap and ArcCatalog

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-9.3, arccatalog, connection

Is it possible to remove/disable the Add Spatial Database Connection and Add OLE DB Connection functionality from ArcMap and ArcCatalog?

Ideally the end user could hit the Add Data button, and the add connections buttons would not show up in the add data dialog.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can remove them from ArcCatalog but I'm not sure about ArcMap. Under preferences, go to general and uncheck "Database Connections." Check this help page out too:  [Using ArcCatalog options](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//006m00000063000000.htm)

ArcGIS 9.3/9.3.1 documentation:  [ArcCatalog:  The Options dialog box](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=The_Options_dialog_box)